# How to change Istio-ingressgateway type from "LoadBalancer" to "ClusterIP"

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using Azure Kubernetes. I installed Istio 1.6.1. It installed the Istio-ingressgateway with LoadBalancer. I don't want to use Istio ingressgateway because I want to kong ingress.

I tried to run below command to change istio-ingress services from LoadBalancer to ClusterIP but getting errors.

```
$ kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -p '{"spec": {"ports": "type": "ClusterIP"}}' -n istio-system

Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character ':' after object key:value pair
```

Not sure if I can make the changes and delete and re-create istio-ingress service?

Comment: Not sure why you need to do that. Ingressgateway is used as the gateway between client outside the cluster to talk to service inside the cluster. If you change the type field to ClusterIP, it will not be accessed from outside the cluster.

Comment: Yes, I know but we want to use Kong-ingress instead of Istio-ingress

Comment: @VikasKalra Have you tried editing svc using kubectl edit svc ?
Also try kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -p '{"spec": {"type": "ClusterIP"}}' -n istio-system

Comment: @sachin I tried kubectl patch svc but getting errors msg "Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character ':' after object key:value pair"  Look like my syntax is not correct. Can anyone please confirm if it is correct syntax ?

Comment: @VikasKalra have you tried the patch svc command I gave?

Comment: The payload you're sending isn't valid JSON.  Try putting an extra pair of curly braces around `{"type": "ClusterIP"}`.  That may not _work_ (if the service keeps its LoadBalancer metadata it won't be a valid ClusterIP service and the update will fail) but it will get past this immediate error.

Comment: @sachin - I ran the command and looks like that the correct syntax. I am getting ports errors. I think I need to change port settings.                                                                                    kubectl patch svc istio-ingressgateway -p '{"spec": {"type": "ClusterIP"}}' -n istio-system
The Service "istio-ingressgateway" is invalid:
* spec.ports[0].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP'
* spec.ports[1].nodePort: Forbidden: may not be used when `type` is 'ClusterIP'

Comment: @sachin : Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better option would be to reinstall istio without ingress controller. Do not install default profile in istio as it will install ingress controller along with other component. Check the various settings as mentioned in the installation page of [istio](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/istioctl/) and disable ingress controller.

Also check the documentation of using istio and kong together on k8s [page](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/03/18/kong-ingress-controller-and-istio-service-mesh/) and see what needs to be done on kong installation in order for enble communication between kong and other services.

Comment: Thanks Atul !!! Actually I am new to Istio that's why I choose default profile. If I couldn't find any way to change  the type from "LoadBalbcer" to "ClusterIP" . Will try to re-install . Thanks for your reply

Comment: Yes, everyone would start with default profile only. Since everyone next progression is customized istio, customized profile is better option. Making service as ClusteredIP might cause one routing hop in the application and would suggest avoid doing that (for production)